# MySQL select until 3 days of rows are met

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to select dates including today through + 3 days but when nothing exists for a day, continue until 3 days is met, but do not go further than 3 days. I feel like I'm on the right track, but still far from solving it. My thought logic would be something like this?

```
SELECT
 date,
 (SELECT date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN (MAX(date) - CURDATE()) AND (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS datediff
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN date AND datediff
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are there multiple rows for each "date"?  Do you want just the dates, not the rest of the data in the rows?  (`SELECT DISTINCT DATE ...`)  You can put expressions in  the `WHERE` clause -- what you have won't work.  Show us some sample data and the desired resultset.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! **Critical** to answering this question is your version of MySQL - please **always** include it, either in the text of the question itself and/or as a tag!